# Qt web browser (4.7.0) cannot display the content of website

Tags: javascript, c++, html, qt

I am building an embedded system, which use C/C++ to call a html5/JavaScript application as a User interface and QtWebkit to connect JavaScript and C/C++.
When I call a web browser of Qt, the web browser displays  Javascript code instead of the content of the website.
Please help me! Thanks in advance!

I'm using Qt 4.7 and my embedded system was built on linux. When I use Flash for creating User interface, the web browser runs ok.

```
//running main thread to show User interface
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(qtArgc/*argc*/,qtArgv/*argv*/);
    CHDMainApp  *m_pHDMainApp = NULL;
    m_pHDMainApp = new CHDMainApp();
    m_pHDMainApp->showFullScreen();
    bool returnValue = app.exec();
}

//running sub-thread to show web browser
bool JoinQThread()
{
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(data);
    refQtApp = new BrowserApplication(jqtArgc2, (char**)jqtArgv2);
    refQtApp->moveToThread(thread);
    qRegisterMetaType<QWSServer::WindowEvent>("QWSServer::WindowEvent");
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), refQtApp, SLOT(newMainWindow()));
    thread->start();
    return true;
}


BrowserMainWindow *BrowserApplication::newMainWindow()
{
    BrowserMainWindow *browser = new BrowserMainWindow();
    m_mainWindows.prepend(browser);
    browser->showMaximized();
    this->open_newUrl("http://www.google.com",false);
    this->exec();
    return browser;
}
```

[image: screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Are you using `QWebView`?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall : Yes, I am. I am using QWebView to display User interface

Comment: Can you show the QWebView related code?

Comment: @ksimons: what did you mean? What part did you want to know? I used Qt webbrowser demo for my project!

Comment: Did you check if the plugins are enabled in the original source. 
    
    webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginEnabled, true)

Comment: Yes, I did.
QWebSettings* default_settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
default_settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled,true);

Comment: Qt 4.7.0 is no longer supported, you could try 4.8.5 or 5.2 and see what happens. I have an application with web-gui that works fine on 4.8.1 and fails to render properly on 4.7.0 because of «too modern» JS and HTML5.

Comment: My system does not support Qt 4.8 :(. Thanks.